# R: legend expression how to add comma between two values and how to supress scientific notation

Tags: r, plot, expression, legend, plotmath

I'm trying to format the legend in my plot, but I have to use expression() because of greek and superscripts.  However, when I want to display r^2 = 0.45, P<0.0001, I get r^2 = 0.45 P<1e-04, when I type in

```
legend(expression(r^2==0.9230~~P<0.0001))
```

I tried looking up the list() function but it doesn't help with the commas.  I couldn't find anything on using decimals in the expression() function either.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For scientific notation, R uses a "penalty system". Check `?options` under `scipen`. When `options(scipen=HighNumber)`, it will be less inclined to use scientific notation - and more inclined at a negative number. Default is zero. In this instance, if you use paste as Josh is suggesting, it won't try to convert to scientific anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `paste()` (within the call to `expression()`) to splice together character strings and unquoted expressions. The unquoted bits will be evaluated using the special rules exhibited by `example(plotmath)` and `demo(plotmath)`, while the character strings will be printed verbatim.

Here's an example (which also uses `phantom()`, because the `<` operator expects/needs **something** to both its left and its right):

```
plot(1)
legend(x = "topleft", 
       legend = expression(paste(r^2==0.9230, ",  ", P<phantom(), "0.0001")))
```

[image]

Comment: A great tip, thank you @Josh O'Brien! Surprisingly, it only works with `paste`, not `paste0`.

Comment: @Bob Interesting point. I think it's because plotmath must have special rules for handling the symbol `paste` passed along to it by `expression()`, just as it special-cases things like `^`, `[]`, `_`, etc. The rules described in `?plotmath` really define a kind of mini-language in which `paste()` has a similar seeming but not actually the same meaning as it does in other R contexts. Does that make sense?

Comment: Dear @Josh O'Brien -- Yes, that makes total sense! I am sure you are correct that the "mini-language" of `plotmath` only defines (or uses) its own version of `paste` and does not define `paste0`. Just thought it was an interesting tidbit, that had me a bit perplexed for a while and might be useful for others... Thanks again for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative way using `substitute` that avoids `phantom`:

```
plot(1)
options(scipen=10)
legend(x = "topleft", 
       legend = substitute(list(r^2 == r2, P < p), list(r2=0.923, p=0.0001)))
```

[image]